# Why does the splice method return undefined when removing at a valid index position?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Why does the splice method return undefined and doesn't remove the element at position 4 in the following code:

```
var excludedDepartmentsList = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6];
var currentDepartmentId = 5;

var position = $.inArray(currentDepartmentId, excludedDepartmentsList);

if (position > -1) {
    var q = excludedDepartmentsList.splice[position, 1];
    return;
}
```

I have made a test here: http://jsfiddle.net/PnVEb/

Answer (score 13, accepted):

`.splice` is a function and it should be called like `excludedDepartmentsList.splice(position, 1)` and not `excludedDepartmentsList.splice[position, 1]`. Note the brackets changed from `[]` to `()`.

Use `()` like below and it should return `5`

```
excludedDepartmentsList.splice(position, 1)
```

**fixed fiddle:** http://jsfiddle.net/PnVEb/1/

Answer (score 3):

`[]` does not equal `()`

```
var q = excludedDepartmentsList.splice[position, 1];
                                      ^           ^
```

Answer (score 2):

Your syntax is a bit wrong. you type `[]` for splice function but it should be `()`.

`[]` are used for arrays on most of the programming languages and `()` are for the functions/methods as well.

Also you must return `q`

```
if (position > -1) {
    var q = excludedDepartmentsList.splice(position, 1);
    return q;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Man use () in splice method, not []